# how can i update value inside component without refresh page?

Tags: angular, angular6

I have this component.

```
  constructor(private cs : CredentialsService) { 

    this.fullname  = this.cs.getFullname();
    this.address  = this.cs.getAddress();
    this.telp  = this.cs.getTelp();
    this.photo = this.cs.getPhoto();
    if(this.photo == ""){
        this.photo = "https://via.placeholder.com/150x150"
      }else{
        this.photo = "http://localhost:84/ELEARNINGAPI/upload/" + this.photo
      }     this.email  = this.cs.getEmail();

  }
```

and this service `CredentialsService` (which is store the user info from local) .

```
export class CredentialsService {

    credentials : any;

  constructor(private apiservice : LoginapiService) {

    this.credentials = JSON.parse(this.apiservice.getLogginCredentials());
    if(this.credentials == null){
      this.apiservice.logout();
    }
  }

  getFullname(){
    return this.credentials.fullname;
  }

  getEmail(){
    return this.credentials.email;
  }

  getAddress(){
        return this.credentials.address;
  }

  getTelp(){
    return this.credentials.telpno;
  }

  getPhoto(){
    return this.credentials.profilpict;
  }

}
```

and here is my `apiservice.getLogginCredentials()`

```
getLogginCredentials(){
        return localStorage.getItem("Credentials"); 
    }
```

so as you can see in my `component constructor` i get the value from CredientialsService. This is how i set my CredentialsService

```
     this.loginapi.setLogginCredentials("somejson");
      --
     setLogginCredentials(UserInfo){
            localStorage.setItem("Credentials" , JSON.stringify(UserInfo));
        }
```

I have an `update component` to re-set `setLogginCredentials` with new value. So my problem is when i update value with new one , i still need refresh my whole page to refresh the value inside my component constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use reactive aproach. Subscribe to an Observable/Subject and your component will automaticaly update. Here is an example, change it for your needs:

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs";

export class Service {
    loginCred$: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject(this.getLogginCredentials());

    getLogginCredentials() {
        return localStorage.getItem("Credentials");
    }

    setLogginCredentials(UserInfo) {
        const creds = JSON.stringify(UserInfo)
        localStorage.setItem("Credentials", creds);
        this.loginCred$.next(creds);
    }

    getCredsSubject() {
        return this.loginCred$;
    }
}

export class Component {
    private creds: string;
    constructor(private service: Service) {
        service.getCredsSubject().subscribe(creds => {
            this.creds = creds;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I try your way, but when i refresh. the value become empty

Answer (score 0):

Angular automatically updates the views when an event is fired, it's named [change detection](https://blog.angular-university.io/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-really-work/). Such asynchronous events are observable, promises or timeouts.

The problem in your code is that `localStorage.setItem` doesn't fire any event. To work it around you can simulate an event just putting your `setItem` after a timeout of *0s*, or you can use a module like [angular-local-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-local-storage) that will do the magic for you.

In the first case:

```
setTimeout(() =>  localStorage.setItem("Credentials" , JSON.stringify(UserInfo)), 0);
```